# Socket.io with cloudflare cross-origin error 525

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, cloudflare

I have an app in which we are trying to implement notifications with socket.io on node and react. Here is the node app:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();
const server = redis.createClient();
const io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

const redisClients = [
    'demo'
];

const socketPort = 2053;
const cors = require('cors');

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});

redisClients.forEach(c => client.subscribe(c));

client.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    console.log(`${channel} '----' ${message}`)
    var info = JSON.parse(message);
    io.sockets.emit(channel, info);
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("connected socket")

    redisClients.forEach((client) => {
        socket.on(client, function (msg) {
            console.log(`from client  ` + JSON.stringify(msg))
            server.publish(`${client}-server`, JSON.stringify(msg));
        });
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        console.log("client disconnected")
        socket.disconnect();
    });
});

http.listen(socketPort);
```

In the client app locally we tested with some random ports like 7000 et al and the code worked. When deploying to the server we had to change the port to 2053 which is one of the ports opened for secure ssl communication. ssl certificates are being managed by cloudflare (free tier: flexible ssl). Here is the client code in react:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('https://my-domain.com:2053', {
  secure: true,
  reconnect: true
});
class App extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
      socket.on(appName, data => {
        const userNotification = filterUserNotification(
          data,
          String(this.props.userSession.id)
        );
        if (userNotification)
          this.props.dispatch(updateNotifications([userNotification]));
      });
}
```

The Error i get is as follows:

Failed to load https://my-domain.com:2053/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8AzArB: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://my-domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 525.

Can someone please help me figure out what is going wrong here.